# Is there an alternate to Min-Height for ie?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I made a standard layout for a webpage that has a header, sidebar, main content area, and a footer. I'm using flex, and min height, and all browsers I've used it looks great, except when I go on IE. I am running IE11, and according to caniuse.com all the css that I am using is available for IE11. The problem I am having with ie, is the area that I have `min-height:100%;` will have a height of what looks like 0. If I change `min-height` to `height` it will look good until I get to a page where the content has more height than 100%. I was able to recreate this in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xwc60dzv/

If I can provide any additional info I will do my best.

Comment: I couldn't fix this myself, hence a comment, but [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596813/internet-explorer-doesnt-honor-my-min-height-100-with-flexbox) and [this blog from a Google Engineer](http://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/) seem to address the same issue and might prove helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I am attempting to use the info in the links you provided. Will update if proves successful.

Answer (score 0):

Going off the links that Equalsk provided I was able to take the css and add my own into it to recreate the same look as I had originally. Can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gbsrcwb5/1/

Biggest difference I see is that it got rid of the `wraper` changed and place the display in the `body` the min height to `100vh`