# Flexbox justify-content ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I'm working for the first time with **flexbox** but I've got an **internet explorer** problem.

In chrome it looks good. But in internet explorer everything is aligned to the right. How could I fix this?

I already tried to add a default **height** and **min-height** described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371626/flexbox-not-centering-vertically-in-ie) but not working :(

Any ideas?

```css
.column {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.panel {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.center {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.column-small {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: auto;
}

.brand {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #f5f5f1;
    color: #002e5b;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.form-group-item {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 45px;
    text-indent: 5px;
}

.btn-main {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #002e5b;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 45px;
}

.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="panel center">
         <div class="column-small">
             <div class="brand">
                 Login
             </div>
             
             <form>
               <input name="email" class="form-group-item" autofocus="autofocus"                 required="required" type="email" placeholder="Email">
               
               <input name="password" class="form-group-item" required="required"                 type="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord"> 
               
               <button class="btn-main full-width" type="submit">Login</button>
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this tutorial useful for you...https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Do you think I'm using flexbox wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing `margin: auto` on `.column-small`.