# IE flexbox vertical align center and min-height

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to vertical align some text inside a flexbox container that has a min height and it works well except for in ie11, where the content is not centred.

```css
.banner {
  background:#ccc;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 60px;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div id="section-title-1" class="banner banner--theme-1 js-section-title" data-title="Section Title">
    <span>IE is bobbins</span>
</div>
```

I have had a look around and people who have had similar problems are suggesting that [adding a height will fix the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371626/flexbox-not-centering-vertically-in-ie) but obviously this negates the `min-height` so it's not very useful.

Does anyone know a way to get the vertical centring to work in ie with a min-height?

Comment: Just make the parent a flex container. See duplicate for details. [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljbmp74q/1/)

Comment: I tried that, it didn't seem to work perhaps it was the row thing that broke it (see one of the answers below).  Seems to be a better solution than the table-cell hack if you want to answer

Comment: It is a cleaner and more efficient solution in my view. I closed the question as a duplicate, because the issue is addressed in detail in that post.

Comment: You can also make it work with `flex-direction: row`, but you then need to add `flex-grow` to your content item. [revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljbmp74q/2/)

Comment: Ah, nice thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open to detecting and applying different CSS to ie11, you could do something like the following:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/zvrbprka/4/)

```css
.banner {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 60px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  .banner span {
    display: table-cell;
    min-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="section-title-1" class="banner banner--theme-1 js-section-title" data-title="Section Title">
  <span>IE is bobbins</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I was looking at an ie only hack using those media queries, looks like old school table-cell will be the best option

Answer (score 2):

This fix by Chris Wright might be usefull:
https://codepen.io/chriswrightdesign/pen/emQNGZ/

It's based on the idea to wrap flex-direction:column inside a flex-direction:row parent:

```
    .l-flex-parent {
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;

    }
```

Comment: great answer. worked like a charm