# Vertical align with flex model with overflow auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The flexible box model makes it incredibly easy to vertically align things. A problem I consistently encounter however is that when I resize the viewport to a 'too small' size, the inner box will overflow *at the top* despite the element residing in an `overflow: auto` element. In other words, you can still scroll till the bottom (as expected with `overflow: auto`) but it doesn't work the other way round.

```css
#con {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
#center {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="con">
    <div id="center">
        Invisible<br/>
        2<br/>
        3<br/>
        4<br/>
        5<br/>
        6<br/>
        7<br/>
        8<br/>
        9<br/>
        10
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I sort of get why this is happening spec-wise, however I have no idea what the best way is to solve this. **How *can* you align something in the center using the flexible box model, but let the element overflow if it doesn't fit**?

Answer (score 2):

this could be an option: http://jsfiddle.net/jge6ppaz/

```
.concon
{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    display:flex;
    overflow: auto;
    flex:0 0 auto;
    flex-direction:column;
    background: yellow;
    justify-content:center;
}

.con {
  display: flex;
  flex:0 0 auto;
  flex-direction:column;
  max-height:100%;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px red;
}

.center {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  flex:0 0 auto;
  align-self:center;
}
```

and the markup:

```
<div class="concon">
    <div class="con">
        <div class="center">
            contents here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So, turns out this was a duplicate of [Overflow: auto causes vertically centered items to be cut off using Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122341/crucial-difference-between-flexbox-2009-and-2012-in-chrome) (as found by cimmamon himself on chat), however as that question is taking a different angle (2009 vs 2012 flexbox versions) I am not going to self-flag this question as a duplicate.

Quoting the linked answer:

> The beauty of Flexbox is that it offers a lot of different ways to achieve a particular layout. One of the underplayed features of Flexbox is that the value of auto for top and bottom margins really does what it sounds like, and its just what you need here in place of justify-contents/align-items.

So then we simply get:

```css
#con {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
#center {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="con">
    <div id="center">
        Invisible<br/>
        2<br/>
        3<br/>
        4<br/>
        5<br/>
        6<br/>
        7<br/>
        8<br/>
        9<br/>
        10
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Much more elegant than the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/s3bjkqj4/1/

CSS

```
#con {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
display: inline-flex;

  overflow: auto;
}
#center {
  background: green;
  color: white;      
  width:80px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

I am not sure is this you want???

Comment: Not sure how that would apply as centred when it fits (http://jsfiddle.net/s3bjkqj4/9/), that's just stretched out... There is a second paragraph in my answer, right under the code snippets... Might be you missed that ~

Comment: is this fine??? http://jsfiddle.net/s3bjkqj4/12/ or adjust the height of #con

Comment: "How can you align something in the center using the flexible box model, but let the element overflow if it doesn't fit?" If you version fits it's now all over the place: http://jsfiddle.net/s3bjkqj4/14/